# Binomial Distribution Parameter & Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A married couple decided to have $5$ children. Based on gene history, probability that any one of their children will need to wear eye glasses, independent of sex, is $60$%; probability that a child being a boy or a girl are equally $50$%. Let $X$ be the number of children that needs glasses and $Y$ be the number of boys in the family.

Probability distribution tables for $X$ and $Y$:

$$
\begin{array}{}
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{X} & \text{P(X)}\\ 
\hline
\\0 & 0.01024
\\1 & 0.07680
\\2 & 0.23040
\\3 & 0.34560
\\4 & 0.25920
\\5 & 0.07776
\end{array}
&
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Y} & \text{P(Y)}\\ 
\hline
\\0 & 0.03125
\\1 & 0.15625
\\2 & 0.31250
\\3 & 0.31250
\\4 & 0.15625
\\5 & 0.03125
\end{array}
\end{array}
$$
Are the tables correct?

Both $X$ and $Y$ are binomial distributions. What are the parameter values?

What is $P(X=E(X))?$

Let $W$ be the number of girls that wear glasses. What is $P(W=E(W))?$

Comment: Houston, we lost zero.

Comment: Zero is back, we happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first table is wrong.  Its probabilities should add up to 1.  The second table is correct. X ~ Bin(5, 0.6).  Y ~ Bin(5,0.5).

Comment: I think when someone edited the data into the table format he deleted a 0. I meant P(X=5)=0.0776. Would that be a correct value?

Comment: @user60852 Yes, but you also need to add P(X=0) and P(Y=0) as well.  So in fact the second table is incomplete.  Can you edit your question?